# Wordpress posts don't show up

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently moved my wordpress to a new host and I get the following error on the home page:

```
Not Found
Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.
```

The corresponding code (in index.php) is:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    ...

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
  <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
  <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
  <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't find any posts to show?

I'd really appreciate any help. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deactivate all plugins. Make sure that all WordPress files were transferred successfully. Resave your permalink structure in Options > Permalinks.

Answer (score 1):

a few things to check:

- That the homepage is set to view posts (Settings > Reading)
- That the correct theme has been set (Appearance > Themes)
- The domain name is correct for the new host - that it isn't forwarding you back to an old domain. (Settings > General)

another option is to start again with a new wordpress setup and using Tools > Export and Tools > Import you can transfer all your old content.

hope that helps.
Josh

Comment: have you tried my idea of an export and reimport of your data on a blank new wordpress setup?

Answer (score 1):

Check/delete .htaccess and reset permalinks. [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and  [Using Permalinks « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

Answer (score 0):

If you switched hosts the first thing I would check is your database connection string stored in your wp-config.php file.

You'll need to update this with the path/user/password to your new database.

Comment: Yes, its correct, I can login to the admin and see the (240) existing posts and I can do almost everything.